# bPopup.js - Open a modal popup automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying for usage bPopup.js for open automatically my advertisement within the modal popup.

The code is this:

```
            $('element_to_pop_up').bPopup({
            content:'iframe', //'ajax', 'iframe' or 'image'
            contentContainer:'.content',
            loadUrl:'http://dinbror.dk/blog' //Uses jQuery.load()
        });
```

How I can do for set the modal popup for auto open?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question. Do you want to open the modal once your page is loaded? Just wrap your code within $(document).ready() function

Comment: Yes, open the modal once the page is loaded. Because in default it open on button click. Ok, I try $.ready() function.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. It will run the code once the page is loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('element_to_pop_up').bPopup({
        content: 'iframe', //'ajax', 'iframe' or 'image'
        contentContainer: '.content',
        loadUrl: 'http://dinbror.dk/blog' //Uses jQuery.load()
    });
});
```